# Out-File only if Results are available. No Zero K files

Tags: powershell, pipeline

Is there a way when you use `Get-ChildItem` with a `Where-Object` clause to have it produce the results in a text file only if there are results?

```
Get-ChildItem -path \\$server\e$ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -eq help.txt} | `
out-file "c:\temp\$server.txt"
```

The above will produce a file regardless if there are results.  I'm having trouble telling implementing the logic to only create when results are available.

Comment: Note: The backtick (`) isn't necessary in a script, since the pipe (|) is already a continue character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it that way. You'll have to do it in 2 parts:

```
$results = Get-ChildItem -path \\$server\e$ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -eq help.txt}
if ($results) {
    $results | out-file "c:\temp\$server.txt"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work how you want if you use `Set-Content` instead of `Out-File`.

```
Get-ChildItem -path \\$server\e$ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -eq help.txt} | 
Set-Content "c:\temp\$server.txt"

#or

gci -R \\$server\e$ |? Name -eq "help.txt" | sc "c:\temp\$server.txt"
```

Comment: thank you.  I tested your code as well and it works.  Both solutions offered here work.